# Flask: What is the use of __init__.py vs run.py? And are blueprints standard things to use in most Flask web applications?

Tags: python, flask

I recently started getting into Flask web dev and I've probably gone through 5 different courses/tutorials now, and they all seem to have different ways/conventions of doing things. I was hoping I could receive some clarity here!

1. Is __init__.py mandatory? I see some tutorials use them and some don't. From my understanding, simpler projects don't have a need for __init__.py due to their simplicity and lack of modules.
2. Do I need a [run.py](https://run.py)? Again, I seem some tutorials use them and some don't so I'm confused on this one. From my knowledge, it seems like [run.py](https://run.py) is used to initialize the app while __init__.py is used to initialize packages (folders)? If so why do some people only use __init__.py?
3. Are blueprints a standard thing used in nearly all flask-based web apps? I ask because some courses seem to teach them as basic concepts, while others simply don't use them. What's the difference between using blueprints and simply just "importing" the module? Why do some projects use them while others don't?
4. Should the following block exist in essentially every module to ensure that it's not the main module being run?

​

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

5. Following up on the blueprint stuff, I have a project I use as a flask playground in order for me to mess around in a useless flask project for me to mess around without worrying I'm messing up a real project. I'm currently importing a "[users.py](https://users.py)" file for me to try out SQL Alchemy. I'm following a tutorial on SQL Alchemy where they do not use blueprints, thus simple do the standard app=Flask(__name__) thing. However, I'm using blueprints and have this sliver of code:

​

```
# Initialize as blueprint
users = Blueprint('users', __name__, url_prefix="/users")
# Load .env.local file and specify relative path
load_dotenv(dotenv_path="./.env.local") 
# Database config
users.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "mysecretkey"
users.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get("SQLITE_URI", "")
users.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
```

The tutorial uses "app.config" obviously, but my "app" exists in my __init__.py and not in this [users.py](https://users.py) , so is there a way of using config in this users file? Should it be done in __init__.py instead?

Sorry for the lengthy post of questions, thank you in advance for anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 14):

I can answer a few questions from your list that I understood.

**Question1**

**init**.py is not a mandatory file. Files named `__init__.py` are used to mark directories on disk as Python package directories. So it really depends on your structure of projects. Ideally if you have a project with multiple folders, you might have to make them as python package directories.

Here is an example. If you have the files

```
project/my_app/__init__.py
project/my_app/module.py
```

you can import the code in `module.py` as

```
from my_app import module
```

If you remove the `__init__.py` file, Python will no longer look for submodules inside that directory, so attempts to import the module will fail.

Comment: Thank you for answering! What you said makes sense, basically python package directories essentially require __init__.py, since that's kind of how the package gets recognized by Python.

In the same file structure you posed, would you also have init.py under the project directory? Under the my_app directory? How would that compare to using run.py instead of init.py?

Comment: Yes, I can have `__inti__.py` in the project directory as well. That will enable me to import any python files I might have in the `project/` directory itself.

Comment: I cannot understand 2nd part of your question. How is `run.py` and ` __init__.py` related?

Comment: It might be due to my lack of understanding of proper Flask file structure. In your file structure example, I would have init.py inside my project directory and I would use this to initialize my entire app (instead of using run.py). So my question is, is there a difference in initializing your Flask app with init.py vs run.py? Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: Understood now. Yes, there is a small difference. Adding explanation in the answer for question 2.

Comment: Can someone explain why `app = Flask(__name__)` is also needed if a file is also called __init__.py? Aren't they both doing the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

**Question 2**

Ideally yes, `run.py` is used to initialize or start the server application. You may also see the file named `app.py` being used instead at some places.

If you are creating a `flask` application and want your api's to be exposed for use, you will have to start or run your flask app.

`app.run(debug=True)` does this.

Regarding difference between `app.py` and `__init__.py` :

- `run.py` --> If you want to start your application, you will have to explicitly execute `run.py` file.
- '`__init__.py` --> The code in **init**.py is run whenever you import anything from the package. That includes importing other modules in that package.

Comment: Currently, my Flask application consists of Flask_Playground, containing __init__.py and users.py where init.py creates the Flask app with app=Flask(__name__). I set my FLASK_APP=Flask_Playground, and I go to my CLI and run "flask run". I do not have a run.py. So in this scenario, what advantage would run.py provide, since my app appears to run without issue? Thank you!

Comment: This is from Python Documentation : `In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the __all__ variable, described later.`

Comment: Since __init__.py can also be used to execute any regular python code, in your case starting the application is being done through this file. You don't need `run.py`.

Comment: I see, so what advantage would run.py provide that init.py would not provide? What is the advantage/purpose of using run.py in a larger application?

Comment: For large applications, it is suggested by  `flask` documentation that initializing the flask app to be done in `__init__.py`.  Here is a link that can help `https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/`

Comment: There is one more difference - if you use `__init__.py` then by default debug mode is off. Tu turn it on you need to set the environment variable `FLASK_ENV=development`

Answer (score 2):

**Question 4**

Simple answer is NO.

The statement `if __name__ == '__main__':` is used only if you expect the python file to be executed using its file name.

If you have a python file that only has helper functions and does not do anything else, you may not include this statement.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your fifth question.

if we want to make a simple Flask application, then use python module to place the application config, application instance, and other things that needed to be placed there. We run the application with the module as the startup file in the command:

```
python app.py
```

If we want to make a larger flask app than a simple application, then use packages. We have `__init__.py` file inside that package folder, in this file we config the app, make the app instance, and other things that needed to be placed there. For example flaskr/`__init__.py`

At this point, we can't run the application using the modules as the startup file as a simple application does. This is the code we use run the package flask app:

```
flask -app thefolderthathas__init__file run
```

or go to the folder where you place the folder that has `__init__.py` file in it, and run:

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
export FLASK_DEBUG=TRUE (Use this command if you are in the development mode, not in the production stage)
flask run
```

Blueprint is usually used for more larger applications. Blueprint helps us to divide larger applications into smaller groups.

Blueprint is not actually application. Blueprint is set of operations that can be registered in the applications. You register your blueprint to the app instance in the `__init__.py` file.

When a blueprint is registered in the application instance, you can have routes(URL) and config from the blueprint on your application. Blueprint records its operations to execute them when registered.

The application instance is still in `__init__.py`, and your blueprint is in users.py so we can register your blueprint from users.py to the application instance in `__init__.py`, then we can have the blueprint's config and routes(URL) in the application.

And you can't unregister the blueprint once the application is created unless you destroy your application.

CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

This also caused lots of confusion for me at the beginning, and while I'm still developing my understanding around these topics, [this paragraph](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world#:%7E:text=The%20application%20will%20exist%20in%20a%20package.%20In%20Python%2C%20a%20sub%2Ddirectory%20that%20includes%20a%20__init__.py%20file%20is%20considered%20a%20package%2C%20and%20can%20be%20imported.%20When%20you%20import%20a%20package%2C%20the%20__init__.py%20executes%20and%20defines%20what%20symbols%20the%20package%20exposes%20to%20the%20outside%20world) helped me conceptualize when to use "__ init __.py" (your first question). The paragraph says, quoting Miguel:

> The application will exist in a package. In Python, a sub-directory that includes a **init**.py file is considered a package, and can be imported. When you import a package, the **init**.py executes and defines what symbols the package exposes to the outside world.

So basically, if a sub-directory (folder) inside your website has an "__ init __.py" file, it will be considered a package which can be imported.

Regarding Flask, the application will exist in a package, and its "__ init __.py" file *will define what symbols the package exposes to the outside world*.

1. [https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world#:~:text=The%20application%20will%20exist%20in%20a%20package.%20In%20Python%2C%20a%20sub%2Ddirectory%20that%20includes%20a%20__init__.py%20file%20is%20considered%20a%20package%2C%20and%20can%20be%20imported.%20When%20you%20import%20a%20package%2C%20the%20__init__.py%20executes%20and%20defines%20what%20symbols%20the%20package%20exposes%20to%20the%20outside%20world](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world#:%7E:text=The%20application%20will%20exist%20in%20a%20package.%20In%20Python%2C%20a%20sub%2Ddirectory%20that%20includes%20a%20__init__.py%20file%20is%20considered%20a%20package%2C%20and%20can%20be%20imported.%20When%20you%20import%20a%20package%2C%20the%20__init__.py%20executes%20and%20defines%20what%20symbols%20the%20package%20exposes%20to%20the%20outside%20world)

Edit: Quoted the relevant information from the link to avoid losing context in case the site's content changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34034631)